# Oracle Apex set select list value in session state without submit page on change

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-19.2

How save selected value from select list in session state without submit page on change?

Example work with submit page!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a dynamic action on change of P245_YEAR
Action type: "Execute Server-side Code"
Language: PL/SQL
PL/SQL Code:

```
NULL;
```

Items to submit: P245_YEAR